# I have a Div Element acting as a button but it will only work once

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I am 11 years old and I started learning Javascript a couple of months ago, So I am trying to make a page where if you scroll down too much it will take you back to the top so I made a Div element that fills up a large space and onmouseover it will take you back up to the top but if you try it a second time it won't do anything. Please help. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please show us some code that reproduces your problem. You tell a mechanic that your car is making a funny noise, he can't help you. You bring your car to the mechanic, he can actually fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my understanding of your problem is right. You have a div and you want to go up each time you scroll too much.

As an example of how to handle the scroll in vanilla JavaScript you can have a look at the document for the onscroll event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      #container {
        height: 500px;
        width: 515px;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      #foo {
        height: 1000px;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: #777;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="foo"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var container = document.getElementById('container');
      container.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
        // Get top and left value
        var top = container.scrollTop
        if (top > 400) {
          // Go to the top
          container.scrollTop = 0;
        }
      }, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example the contained element is bigger that the container so the container becomes scrollable with the `overflow: auto;` css property.

The scripts applies a onscroll event that checks the scroll value of the container and reset it to 0 when it exceed an arbitrary value (400 in the example).

I hope this has been useful to your work.